# Checking to see if array field is null or empty?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowflake, how can I filter for null or empty array fields in a column?

Column has an empty **[]** or string of values in that bracket, tried using `array_size(column_name, 1) > 0` but array_size does not function,

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to filter them in or out?

Either way the array_size should work. although there's no second argument
`where column_name is not null and array_size(column_name) != 0` worked for me

If you're specifically looking to filter to the records that have an empty array, this approach works too, although it's a little odd.
`where column_name = array_construct()`

**Edit:** It seems like your issue is that your column is a string. There's a few ways to work around this

- Change your column's datatype to a variant or array
- Parse your column before using array functions `array_size(TRY_PARSE_JSON(column_name)) != 0`
- Compare to a string instead `column_name is not null and column_name != '[]'`

Comment: get an error of Can not convert parameter 'ARRAY_CONSTRUCT()' of type [ARRAY] into expected type

Comment: what's your column's data type? an ARRAY or VARIANT?
If it's a VARIANT, you might have a value in there that isn't an ARRAY.

Comment: what's the last bit of that error? I managed to get a similar error by converting it into a string first, which does indicate a data type issue.

Try `where array_size(column_name::array) = 0` perhaps? That still relies on the string to be consistently in the right format though, so changing the data type is generally preferrable.

Comment: full error was Can not convert parameter 'ARRAY_CONSTRUCT()' of type [ARRAY] into expected type [VARCHAR(16777216)]

Comment: Trying to filer out records that have just [] or include records that have a string or values in the []

Comment: when I try olumn_name is null or array_size(column_name) = 0 I get  Invalid argument types for function 'ARRAY_SIZE': (VARCHAR(16777216))

Comment: See edit in answer for handling your data type issue. there's a few options.

Answer (score 1):

If the column is string, it has to be parsed first:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE ARRAY_SIZE(TRY_PARSE_JSON(column_name)) > 0;
      -- excluding NULLs/empty arrays
```